# Concat multiple rows also when they do not exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, concatenation

I need to concat multiple row column values into one column. I know I can use GROUP_CONCAT for that. But it does not fit my needs. This is my query:

```
  SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(twv.value ORDER BY twv.id ASC SEPARATOR ';') as needed_values
  FROM table_with_values twv
  WHERE twv.valuetype_id IN (9,12,13,15,17,29)
  GROUP BY twv.person_id
```

The problem is that when a row with for example valuetype_id = 13 is not found, this value will of course not be concatenated.

How can i accomplish that in the case a person_id does not have a value for valuetype_id = 13 that '-' will be inserted in that part?

Thanks

@Giles
I tried your idea, and later changed it a bit. Tested the query below and it gives me 5 rows instead of the expected 6 (because i'm left joining??).

```
SELECT vid
FROM (SELECT 9 vid UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 29) vids
LEFT JOIN sollicitant_profiel sp1 ON (sp1.vraag_id = vids.vid)
WHERE sp1.sollicitant_id = 1
```

Whereas this one does work and gives 6 rows as expected:

```
SELECT vids.vid, vids2.vid
FROM (SELECT 9 vid UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 29) vids
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 9 vid UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 17) vids2 ON (vids.vid = vids2.vid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(twv.value,'-') ORDER BY twv.id ASC SEPARATOR ';') as needed_values
FROM table_with_values twv
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 9 vid UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 29) vids
ON vids.vid = twv.valuetype_id
GROUP BY twv.person_id
```

Not having your values I am unable to test it. The "vids" sub-select may be better as a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IF_NULL , it returns second parameter '-' when GROUP_CONCAT IS NULL.

```
SELECT
  IF_NULL(GROUP_CONCAT(twv.value ORDER BY twv.id ASC SEPARATOR ';'),'-') as needed_values
FROM table_with_values twv
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 9 vid UNION SELECT 12 UNION SELECT 13 UNION SELECT 15 UNION SELECT 17 UNION SELECT 29) vids
ON vids.vid = twv.valuetype_id
GROUP BY twv.person_id
```